# mysql not finding a & character in name

Tags: php, mysql

in my db I have saved name like this: `Hotel Stella Makadi & Spa`, if I make a sql query

```
SELECT b.content FROM posts as b where b.title="Hotel Stella Makadi & Spa"
```

result is empty. Where can be problem?

Comment: Check in your DB if it got saved as &amp;

Comment: it is there exactly Hotel Stella Makadi & Spa, if I use search function in phpmyadmin it finds it

Comment: Did you try to run the raw query in PMA?

Comment: yes, I did. Result is empty

Comment: @dontHaveName Then that means it is not in the form you think it is. What result do you get when using `WHERE b.title LIKE 'Hotel Stella%'` or `WHERE b.title = 'Hotel Stella Makadi &amp; Spa'`.

Comment: hm, really interesting now that select( SELECT b.content FROM posts as b where b.title="Hotel Stella Makadi & Spa")  works in phpmyadmin but still doesn't work in php file

Comment: Could u put here the full code to execute the query?

Comment: $row = $wpdb->get_row( $sql ); it's just that

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT b.content FROM posts as b where b.title LIKE 'Hotel Stella Makadi & Spa'
```

Comment: this query works in phpmyadmin but still doesn't work in php file

Comment: If it works in phpmyadmin, have u seen ur log files to check if the query generates some kind of error?
If you just execute this "SELECT b.content FROM posts", do you got any results?

Comment: there is not any error, have no idea what can be wrong because other names without "&" work normal